# lastElementChild for selecting the last li in ul?

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I'm trying to select the last item in

```
<ul id="list_1">
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Orange</li>
    <li>Grape</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Mango</li>
</ul>
```

so I made

```
var ul    = document.getElementById("list_1");
var mango = ul.lastElementChild;
```

So far, the selection seems to be working. But I'm not sure if I used lastElementChild correctly. Would

```
var mango =  ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[4];
```

be the proper one to use?

Comment: Be careful with [*compatibility*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.lastElementChild), IE 8 and earlier get *lastElementChild* wrong. The *getElementsByTagName* approach is more reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That use of `lastElementChild` is fine, it will always refer to the *last* element that's a direct child of the list.

`ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[4]` will always give you the fifth, which may not be the last (although it is in this case).

Beware, though, that if you need to support IE8, IE8 doesn't support `lastElementChild`. (IE9 and up do.) To include IE8, you can get the last element reliably like this:

```
var ul    = document.getElementById("list_1");
var mango = ul.children[ul.children.length - 1];
```

Unlike `childNodes`, `children` only contains child *elements* and not other kinds of children (text nodes and such), and it's supported on IE8.

Comment: According to [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.lastElementChild), IE 8 gets it wrong though (if not, the MDN article should be updated).

Comment: @RobG: As far as I can tell, the `lastElementChild` article you linked to is wrong (I have to admit not having looked at MDN, I just tested it directly before saying IE8 didn't have `lastElementChild`), IE8 doesn't seem to have `lastElementChild` at all: http://jsbin.com/miharu/1 The [`children` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) also appears to be wrong when it says that IE8 includes comment nodes: http://jsbin.com/miharu/2

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks for the heads up about ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[4] not always selecting the last element. It reminded me of the fact that there will be times I wouldn't know which would be the last element.